# Get separate record for each value

Tags: java, android

I have a list, `List<String> myList=new ArrayList<String>();` This list contains the list of countries that I am dealing with.

I am dealing with several records. I need to calculate in such a way that a separate entry for records as per country is sorted.I am using the following logic

```
for(int zTmp = 0; zTmp<myList.size(); zTmp++)
{
    System.out.println("COUNTRY IS"+myList.get(zTmp));
    if((record).contains(myList.get(zTmp)))
    {  
        // my next step
    }
}
```

How ever I find that each and every record is entering after the if condition. The records are alphabetically sorted as per countries, and records of every country are together. Please correct me.

This is my String

```
RECORD 1@India$
RECORD 2@India$
RECORD 3@United Arab Emirates$
RECORD 4@United Arab Emirates$
RECORD 5@United Kingdom$
```

Sorted as per country name.
I need to give a condition such that it enters in the loop for every country ie say RECORD 1,RECORD 2 calculation must be done break; record 3 ,4 break; record 5 like this.
Hope I am more clear now.

Comment: Better practice things - first it's better to use for(String zTmp:myList){}. second don't use mylist.get(zTmp) twice.

Comment: post some inputs where `if` should be `false` but it's entering `if` block.

Comment: Your question is not clear. could you rephrase it?

Comment: Could you please better frame your question or add the left out parts of the code to make it seem more clearer.

Comment: I have modified the question,tried to explain the question more clearly

Comment: Still elaborate more specifically.

Comment: are these 5 `string`s or two `string`s?

Comment: they are five string, I need to calculate 3 records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The desired output has been achieved by using do while loop
here is the snippet

```
                 int zTmp=0;
                 do  
            {
                String country=myList.get(zTmp);
                if(inputCountry.equals(country))
                {

                    CalcDays(tmpTokens[iTmp]);
                    myDateList.clear();
                }zTmp++;
            }while(zTmp<myList.size());
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mean this?

```
String currentCountry = "";
for (String record : myList) {
    // Regex for entire string "^....$"
    // Country between '@' and '$' (the latter escaped)
    String country = record.replaceFirst("^.*@(.*)\\$$", "$1");
    if (!country.equals(currentCountry)) {
        currentCountry = country;
        ... // Deal with next country
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int zTmp = 0; zTmp<myList.size(); zTmp++)
{
    System.out.println("COUNTRY IS"+myList.get(zTmp));
    if((record).contains(myList.get(zTmp)))
    {  
        // my next step
    }
}
```

Your `if` condition will result in `false` only if `record` doesn't contain a country which is not present in complete `myList`, otherwise **It will be `true` atleast in one iteration.**

In comments you wrote:

> You want to calculate 3 records

instead of using `myList`, create a separate list (say `myChoosenCountriesList`) of having those countries only when you want `if` condition to become true.

Then replace your code with following: (Note other improvments also)

```
int countryCount = myChoosenCountriesList.size();
for(int zTmp = 0; zTmp<countryCount; zTmp++)
{
    String countryName = myChoosenCountriesList.get(zTmp);
    System.out.println("COUNTRY IS"+countryName);
    if(record.contains(countryName))
    {  
        // my next step
    }
}
```